# Why does my hair look like tubes?

Tags: modeling, rendering, 3d-view, hair, settings

So I've been using the new blender hair system and the individual hair strands look like this.
how do I fix it?

[image]

Comment: Only you know what settings you used to produced that result so how is anyone here supposed to know how you did it? You'll need to include a more detailed explanation of your settings and some more images of them too if possible.

Comment: Wild guess: have you applied the *Scale* to the emitter object and the hair curves object? Have you set the hair curve thickness with the *Set Hair Curve Profile* GN modifier? (It's in the Asset Browser in the *Write* category.) Also, make sure to set the Eevee Render setting Curves > Shape to Strip so the thickness is displayed properly in the viewport and for Eevee. -- Feel free to add screenshots of the objects, modifiers, GN node trees, etc, or to provide a demo file here (https://blend-exchange.com/)

Comment: Oh hey, the hair curve node worked! thank you! and sorry for the lack of information, I'm still pretty new to this blender help thing.